# FormulaR1C1 in For Each and If function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would my macro to test some value and based on the result use a particular formula. My implementation with `For Each` and `If` control structures doesn't lead me to the expected result. The formula is not working and I get runtime error instead.

```
Dim RelRowR As Range

Set RelRowR = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Resize(LR1,1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each RelRowR In RelRowR
  If RelRowR.Value = "C1" Then
     RelRowR.Offset(0, 17).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(R[0]C[-15],'[SD Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!R5C19:R15C31,VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-3],'[SD Workbook.xlsx].Sheet1'!R36C4:39C5,2,0),0)"
  End If
Next RelRowR
```

Comment: What is your runtime error and on which line?  Have you manually entered your formula in a cell to see if it works? You can have your code `Debug.Print` your formula to the immediate window, then copy/paste that formula into a cell and check that it is formed correctly.

Comment: Hi Peter. Thank you for your comment. I have application-defined or object-defined error on my formula.

Comment: Make sure you've [enabled R1C1 References](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T008803_Understanding_R1C1_References.html) first. Then there is a syntax problem with your formula: there should not be a dot `.` in the `VLOOKUP` part of the formula `'[SD Workbook.xlsx].Sheet1'!R36C4:39C5`.  It should be `'[SD Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!R36C4:39C5`